# Bind to datagrid when one of the DataGridTextColumn is a list

Tags: wpf, datagrid, bind

i have datagrid in my project which i bind my attributes collection like this:

```
<DataGrid 
    Grid.Row="1"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Attributes}" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    Margin="5"
    >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="3*" Header="Name" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding name}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="3*" Header="Field" Binding="{Binding field}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="3*" Header="Type" Binding="{Binding type}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="3*" Header="Value" Binding="{Binding value}" />
```

the problem is that name, field and type are string and value is a list. how can i bind it to the Datagrid in this way:

```
Name     Field     Type    Value
-----   -------   ------   -----
name1   xField1   xType1     1
name1   xField1   xType1     2
name1   xField1   xType1     3
name1   xField1   xType1     4
name1   xField2   xType2     5
name2   xField2   xType2     20
name2   xField2   xType2     30
name2   xField2   xType2     40
name3   xField3   xType3     100
```

ItemsSource="{Binding Attributes}" in my case Attributes is a list of 3 values (name1, name2, name3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming like you said value is a List(). If so, you possibly try to make a DataGridTemplateColumn instead of a DataGridTextColumn and make a datatemplate that holds a list or listview then each row will have a listbox/listview that show all the values that apply to that row. If you just want to show the count of value then you leave everything the way it is and just bind Value.Count . Hope this helps a little :)

Comment: Thanks TMan, i wasn't aware of the existence of DataGridTemplateColumn